# Generate inputs using javascript

Tags: javascript, php

```
Number of M.C.Q questions:<input type="number" name="mcq" min="0"/></br>
 </br>
 Number of True/False questions:<input type="number" name="truefalse" 
  min="0"/></br></br>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Generate inputs"/>
```

[Homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n74ra.jpg)

When i enter the number of mcq question and true/false and then submit i want to generate that many number of inputs so i can type my questions with four radio buttons for mcq and 2 radio buttons for true/false.

**Is it possible in javascript?
If no how can i do it in php?**

Comment: Yes it's possible. What have you tried?

Comment: i dont even know where to start??Can you just give me some hint.Thx

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```js
const mcq = document.getElementById('mcq')
const nb = document.getElementById('nb')
const button = document.getElementById('submit')
const res = document.getElementById('fields')

let qn, bn = 0;

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  while (res.firstChild) {
    res.removeChild(res.firstChild);
  };
  qn = mcq.value || 0;
  bn = nb.value || 0;
  for (let i=0; i < qn; i++) {
    let l = document.createElement('span');
    l.innerText = 'Question ' + i;
    let e = document.createElement('input');
    e.setAttribute('id', 'q' + i);
    res.appendChild(l);
    res.appendChild(e);
    for (let i=0; i < bn; i++) {
      let b = document.createElement('input');
      b.setAttribute('type', 'radio');
      b.setAttribute('id', 'r' + i);
      res.appendChild(b);
    }
    res.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
  };
})
```

```html
Number of M.C.Q questions:<input type="number" name="mcq" id="mcq" min="0"/></br>
 </br>
 Number of True/False questions:<input type="number" id="nb" name="truefalse" 
  min="0"/></br></br>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Generate inputs"/>
 <div id='fields'></div>
```

All fields get unique `id` to enable further data gathering.

Comment: This doesn't run in Safari 10.

Comment: @RobG looks like the problem is only here, on SO when I use built-in snippet thing. The same code runs fine for me in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wostex/gvj74dpx/ in Safari.